# Merge two dictionaries of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to merge two dictionaries of dictionaries in aws lambda python 3
This does not work, I am using boto3

```
a = {'Action': 'DELETE', 'ResourceRecordSet': {'AliasTarget': {'HostedZoneId': 'BLABLABLA', 'EvaluateTargetHealth': False, 'DNSName': 'BLABLA'}, 'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'BLABLABLA'}}

b = {'Action': 'UPSERT', 'ResourceRecordSet': {'TTL': 60, 'Type': 'CNAME', 'Name': 'BLABLA', 'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': 'blablabla'}]}}

c = a_dictionary.update(b_dictionary)
print(c)
```

The print command prints none

Comment: What should the resulting dictionary be like for the key `Action`?

Comment: I want it to print 
{'Action': 'DELETE', 'ResourceRecordSet': {'AliasTarget': {'HostedZoneId': 'BLABLABLA', 'EvaluateTargetHealth': False, 'DNSName': 'BLABLA'}, 'Type': 'A', 'Name': 'BLABLABLA'} ,'Action': 'UPSERT', 'ResourceRecordSet': {'TTL': 60, 'Type': 'CNAME', 'Name': 'BLABLA', 'ResourceRecords': [{'Value': 'blablabla'}]}}

Comment: No I have already tried it this merge 2 dictionaries ,I need to merge dictionaries with dictionaries within them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet as posted will raise a name error since the dictionaries are named `a` and `b`, not `a_dictionary` and `b_dictionary`.

That aside, `a.update(b)` updates `a` in place and returns None.

To merge two dictionaries into a new dict, you can splat the dicts:

```
c = {**a, **b}
```

If you're using an older version of Python that doesn't support the syntax, two dicts can be merged with

```
c = dict(a, **b)
```

However, this won't do deep merging, which may be what you'd like -- it will simply overwrite "top-level" entries from `a` with those from `b`.

Comment: AWS Lambda 3.8 does not support ** should have said it sorry.

Comment: Added alternate approach.

Comment: Is there a possibility of doing deep merging with this option?

Answer (score 0):

The `update` function doesn't return new dictionary, it updates the first dictionary. So in your case you should write:

`a.update(b)`

And `a` will have updated data.