# Merge two dictionaries that have dictionaries as key values

Tags: jython-2.7

[Merge two dictionaries of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67459045/merge-two-dictionaries-of-dictionaries)

My question is similar to this one, but the answers don't produce the right result (for me?).

Take these dictionaries:

```
a = {'a': {'a': 1}}
b = {'a': {'b': 2}}
```

I want to produce:

```
c = {'a': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

Using the answers from the quoted question, these all produce:

```
c = a.copy()
c.update(b)

>>
c == {'a': {'b': 2}
```

Consider that a and b might be more complex than this, for example:

```
a = {'a': {'aa': {'aaa': 1}, 'bb': {'bbb': 2}}}
b = {'a': {'bb': {'aaa': 1}, 'bb': {'bbb': 2}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use

```
>>> a['a'].update(b['a'])
>>> a
{'a': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}}
```

Element in dictionary is also dictionary, so you can treat that element as dictionary.
As for more complex example I don't know what result should be. But in general, you can access elements in element as dictionary in nested for loops.